# Extra newline while sending data to a stream using through2 in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, stdout, stdin

I am going through the stream-adventure workshopper from NodeSchool. I was to write a program which piped the process.stdin stream to a stream which was created using through2 module and then pipe that to process.stdout. The stream created using through2 module will convert the input stream characters to uppercase and pipe it to process.stdout. Below is my source code:

```
var through = require('through2');
var write = function(buffer,encoding,next){
        var data = buffer.toString();
        this.push(data.toUpperCase() + '\n');
        next();
}
var end = function (done){
        done();
}
var stream = through(write,end);
process.stdin.pipe(stream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

The problem is that after every 8th chunk of word sent into the stream, an extra newline is printed. Below are 3 test outputs from the verification the workshopper did:

Test 1:

```
TAP version 13
# (anonymous)
ok 1 stream-adventure verify YOURFILE.js
not ok 2 should be equal
  ---
    operator: equal
    expected:
      'METALKIND\nKORVEN\nOSIRIAN\nTHE ERGON\nTYTHONIAN\nLAND OF FICTION BEINGS\nSIRIAN\nKRAAL\nTHE FLOOD\nJADONDAN\n'
    actual:
      'METALKIND\nKORVEN\nOSIRIAN\nTHE ERGON\nTYTHONIAN\nLAND OF FICTION BEINGS\nSIRIAN\nKRAAL\n\nTHE FLOOD\n\nJADONDAN\n\n'
  ...
ok 3 successful exit code

1..3
# tests 3
# pass  2
# fail  1

#########################################
###   YOUR SOLUTION IS NOT CORRECT!   ###
#########################################
```

Test 2:

```
TAP version 13
# (anonymous)
ok 1 stream-adventure verify YOURFILE.js
not ok 2 should be equal
  ---
    operator: equal
    expected:
      'THE BEAST\nANDROZANI TREE\nGAZTAK\nRAXACORICOFALLAPATORIAN\nMAYFLY\nSTIGORAX\nTHE TRICKSTER\nMEGARA\nMENTOR\nHAND OF OMEGA\n'
    actual:
      'THE BEAST\nANDROZANI TREE\nGAZTAK\nRAXACORICOFALLAPATORIAN\nMAYFLY\nSTIGORAX\nTHE TRICKSTER\nMEGARA\nMENTOR\n\nHAND OF OMEGA\n\n'
  ...
ok 3 successful exit code

1..3
# tests 3
# pass  2
# fail  1

#########################################
###   YOUR SOLUTION IS NOT CORRECT!   ###
#########################################
```

Test 3:

```
TAP version 13
# (anonymous)
ok 1 stream-adventure verify YOURFILE.js
not ok 2 should be equal
  ---
    operator: equal
    expected:
      'QETESH\nPELUSHI\nLURMAN\nEVE\nATRAXI\nFLESHKIND\nDALEK\nGEE-JEE FLY\nHEADLESS MONK\nTHE DESTROYER\n'
    actual:
      'QETESH\nPELUSHI\nLURMAN\nEVE\nATRAXI\nFLESHKIND\nDALEK\nGEE-JEE FLY\n\nHEADLESS MONK\n\nTHE DESTROYER\n\n'
  ...
ok 3 successful exit code

1..3
# tests 3
# pass  2
# fail  1

#########################################
###   YOUR SOLUTION IS NOT CORRECT!   ###
#########################################
```

What is the cause of the mysterious extra newline and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra newline is being added by line 4 in your code. To fix you could change line 4 from this:

```
this.push(data.toUpperCase() + '\n');
```

to this:

```
this.push(data.toUpperCase());
```

also the stream-adventure lesson will print their reference solution when you type this in terminal

```
stream-adventure solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add in the '\n' it is already in the stream. I guessing the buffer you are getting is more than one line so that the '\n' is added in at random.